# Access Query To Raise Field Values by a Percentage?

Tags: sql, ms-access, multiplication

Is anyone kindly able to help me write an SQL Access Query to do something like this?

```
Table [Product Properties]

If [nType] = 8

Then [nValue1]*1.1
```

I wish to increase the values of fields in a column by a percentage if the value of the field in another column is '8',

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
Update [Product Properties]
Set [nValue1] = [nValue1] * 1.1
Where [nType] = 8
```